# Extract function interface with generics to a separate type/interface variable

Tags: typescript, generics

Following is a typescript generic example I got from [typescriptlang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

```
function getProperty<Type, Key extends keyof Type>(obj: Type, key: Key) {
  return obj[key];
}

let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

getProperty(x, "a");
getProperty(x, "m");
```

Is it possible to extract the generic type to a type variable in order to reuse it? Tried following but it gives an error

```
type MyType<Type, Key extends keyof Type> = {obj: Type, key: Key}

let x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };


function getPropertyGeneric(params: MyType<x>) {
  return obj[key];
}
```

error is

```
Generic type 'MyType' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

[Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoCc4AdVZQCeAPACpH4A0iA0qkYqgB5SpgAmAzogNYNxgiCvgB8ACjgAjAFYAuYZVQ1+RBfSIBKRAG8AUIkRZ0ILEmkyA2qoC6Abj0BfPXoA26RM0QBeXYgCGCgCMNFIKAEw0EAoAzDQcCgAsiI4OesT4iACyRCKo5Eo0Gkys7Nx8AkJ5oj66Fgp5KgzqDM4uoJCwCCjo2HgExADi7AQwEOK4-lj+ALZcCjl52vqGxlCm5rLWDPZOLmiYOPiEROLMNABE-heaDgd9x8RnlzM3dkA)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question... can you give an example of the result you are looking for?

Comment: @ExplosionPills The second block of code. If I can extract generic type to `MyType`. Actually I wanted this because I'm trying to create redux action type to a similar scenario. I need to define the parameter type as a separate type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the type defined as:

```ts
type MyType<Type, Key extends keyof Type> = {obj: Type, key: Key}
```

you have to provide explicitly 2 type parameters:

```ts
function getPropertyGeneric(params: MyType<typeof x, keyof typeof x>) {
  return params.obj[params.key];
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5EbMN)

But you may use [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) for the second type parameter. And define `MyType` as:

```ts
type MyType<Type, Key extends keyof Type = keyof Type> = {obj: Type, key: Key}
```

The you may provide or omit the second type parameter:

```ts
function getPropertyGeneric2(params: MyType<typeof x, keyof typeof x>) { // no error
  return params.obj[params.key];
}

function getPropertyGeneric1(params: MyType<typeof x>) { // no error
  return params.obj[params.key];
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/ND5nlm)

Also note that you cannot use *value* `x` in *type* position. You have to get it's type with [typeof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator) operator.

Comment: Didn't knew about default types. Thanks